# Difficulty finding Dual

Tags: optimization

**min** $\left \langle a,x \right \rangle$ **subject to** $\left \| x \right \|^2 \le 1$ 
What was done:
$L(x,\lambda) = a^Tx + \lambda^T(x^Tx-1) = a^Tx + \lambda^Tx^Tx-\lambda^T$
 that is, $L(x,\lambda) = inf\{(a^T+\lambda^Tx^T)x\}-\lambda^T$

 Gradients are:
$\nabla f(x) = a$ e $\nabla g(x) = 2x$
Therefore, $\nabla L(x,\lambda) = \nabla f(x) + \lambda \nabla g(x) = 0$
$x^* = \frac{-a}{2\lambda}$
Replacing $x^*$ em $L(x, \lambda)$ we have:
$(a^T + \lambda^T(\frac{-a}{2\lambda})^T)(\frac{-a}{2\lambda}) - \lambda^T$
My doubt is, that when I do this distributivity I end up not seeing the dual.

Answer (score 1):

1. $<a,x>$ is $a^Tx$ not $ax^T$
2. $\lambda$ is a scalar so no point in writing $\lambda^T$
3. When replacing $x^*$ you forget multiplying it with $a^T$
4. You are incorrectly replacing $x^Tx$

Comment: I edited my solution according to your answer, I just left the lambda transposed, because it is a vector of n dimension. Could you verify that it is now correct? Sorry for the writing, because it is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Continuing $(\frac{-a}{2\lambda})a^T + (\frac{-a}{2\lambda})^T\lambda^T(\frac{-a}{2\lambda}) - \lambda^T$

Comment: $\left \langle a,-\frac{a}{2\lambda} \right \rangle + \left \langle \lambda^T(-\frac{a}{2\lambda}),-\frac{a}{2\lambda} \right \rangle - \lambda^T$

Comment: $-\left \langle a,\frac{a}{2\lambda} \right \rangle - \left \langle \lambda^T(\frac{a}{2\lambda}),\frac{a}{2\lambda} \right \rangle - \lambda^T$

Comment: $\lambda$ is $\textbf{not}$ a vector. There is only one constraint in this optimization problem hence it’s just a scalar.